# Add PHP ext-intl on DDEV for Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3

I installed a Magento 2.3 instance with [this](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/cli-usage/#magento-2-quickstart) tutorial. It works like a charm.

But when I do a composer update the system says:

`Install or enable PHP's intl extension.`

I am wondering how to solve the issue to install "intl" in DDEV. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Stop xampp/wamp and than open xampp/php/php.ini and search **`int`** and remove starting semicolon `;`

if you are on Ubuntu than try following instructions

```
sudo apt-get install -y php-intl
```

*You can then check if the extension is installed using this command:*

```
php -m | grep intl
```

**Don't forget to restart Apache server**

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am running a DDEV and no XAMPP. So this solution doesn't work for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with the following steps:

1. Downgrade to Composer 1 as this is fully compatible with Magento 2.3
   In DDEV it is done in .ddev/config.yaml

   composer_version: "1"
2. Running a MacBook with Big Sur I had to install PHP 7.4 manually – [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64684713/update-php-to-7-4-macos-catalina-with-brew) showed me how:

   brew install php@7.4

   brew link --force --overwrite php@7.4

   brew services start php@7.4

   export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"

   export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"